# Defining a base URI using VRaptor3 and Tomcat

Tags: java, vraptor

I am using the `VRaptor` to implement a web service.
I am looking for a way to add a service prefix (e.g. `/v1/*`) to the `URI`.
I want to do it globally not using the `@Path("/v1/")`.

How to do it using this framework and Tomcat? Is it possible to do using the `webxml` (servlet mapping?).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to do that would be specializing VRaptor's `PathAnnotationRoutesParser`, i.e:

```
@Alternative
@Priority(Interceptor.Priority.LIBRARY_BEFORE+10)
public class CustomRouterParser extends PathAnnotationRoutesParser {

    protected CustomRouterParser() {
        this(null, null);
    }

    @Inject
    public CustomRouterParser(Router router, Environment environment) {
        super(router);
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getURIsFor(Method javaMethod, Class<?> type) {
        return "CUSTOM-PREFIX" + super.getURIsFor(javaMethod, type);
    }
}
```

You can see more examples at http://www.vraptor.org/en/docs/components/#customizing-vraptor. Best